# Появление ошибки EOFEXCEPTION

Tags: java

В приведенном примере возникает ошибка EOFException
можно ли узнать причину не появления и как этого избежать?

```
public class Remover {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
        Object object;
        try {
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream("D:\\‘Š‘Š‘Ŝ\KadrPress_jar\\Man\\‘-012251.man"));
            object = objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
            
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\‘Š‘Š‘Ŝ\KadrPress_jar\\Man\\‘-012251.man"));
            oos.writeObject(object);
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> java.io.EOFException  at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2735)
> at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInts(ObjectInputStream.java:3366)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2008)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
> at javax.swing.ImageIcon.readObject(ImageIcon.java:495)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
> at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2232)
> at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2123)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
> at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1412)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
> at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2232)
> at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2123)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
> at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2341)
> at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2265)
> at
> java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2123)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
> at formaView.KadrPressMain.R

emover.main(Remover.java:12)

Comment: Если читать уже нечего.

Comment: Можно узнать ошибка закладывается ещё при записи?

Comment: Нет, при чтении.

Comment: Файл записывается корректно, но потом получается битым, который не прочитать, не понятно в каком месте появляется ошибка.

Comment: ObjectInputStream натыкается на конец файла там, где он этого не ожидает.
Возможно, файл пустой или вообще отсутствует?

Comment: Может ли возникнуть ошибка если был оборван процесс записи?